# How to fetch the last value in a column from mysql database using python?

Tags: python, mysql

I have created a table 'log' with three rows:

```
serial_number   date   temp
```

This table gets updated every ten seconds.

My question is how to fetch the last value from the 'temp' row using python.

Comment: Three rows or three columns?

Comment: @Gordon thanks for your reply. I want fetch the last updated value from the "value" row

Comment: there are three rows 
serial_number     date     temp

if I have the last updated values as : 
serial_number: 891   Date: 18:03:2015 16:20   Temp: 33 
so how to fetch the value 33 from temp row using python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean "three columns", use `order by` and `limit`:

```
select value
from table t
order by date desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: @Rao . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted this answer?

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can use cursor.lastrowid to get the last row ID inserted on the cursor object, or connection.insert_id() to get the ID from the last insert on that connection.

Comment: thanks for your reply.
if I have the last updated values as :
serial_number: 891 Date: 18:03:2015 16:20 Temp: 33
so how i fetch value 33 using python.